# função jquery .change não funciona em mobile

Tags: php, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

O script abaixo realiza uma busca das cidades de acordo com o estado selecionado em um option input no HTML e ele funciona perfeitamente no navegador em computadores, porém nos navegadores mobile ele não faz nada.

```
<!-- Busca Cidades -->
<script>
            //quando seleciona um option
            $("#uf_natal").change(function(){            
                //pega o valor do value do option
                let id = $(this).val();  
                
                //faz a requisião ajax no arquivo php
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?= url("/buscar/cidades") ?>",
                    method:"POST",
                    dataType: "HTML",
                    data: {"id": id}
                    
                }).done(function(data){
                    $("#cidade_nasc").html(data);
                });            
            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a propriedade [.On](https://api.jquery.com/on/) para obter isso melhor.

```
<!-- Busca Cidades -->
<script>
     $(document).on('change', '#uf_natal', function(){

        //pega o valor do value do option
        let id = $(this).val();  
        
        //faz a requisião ajax no arquivo php
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?= url("/buscar/cidades") ?>",
            method:"POST",
            dataType: "HTML",
            data: {"id": id}
            
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#cidade_nasc").html(data);
        });          

    });
</script>
```